# ¿Cómo pongo un fondo responsivo en una aplicación android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy desarrollando una aplicación Android basándome en este diseño que hice en Figma

[image: Diseño en Figma]

Lo que quisiera es poder poner el círculo de abajo como fondo y podría hacer una imagen en png o jgp pero quisiera que no pierda calidad y mantenga la relación de aspecto independientemente de la resolución de la pantalla.

He intentado haciendo el semicírculo en drawable y logro aplicarlo y se ve bien en la vista previa pero cuando instalo el programa en mi teléfono el xml del semicírculo se corre varios pixeles hacia arriba. Saludos

Comment: Sería buena idea agregar el xml que estas implementando.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres puedes usar una imagen de fondo que se ajuste siempre al ancho. En tu caso como solo abarca el fondo debe irte bien con el uso de `android:scaleType="fitXY"` como en este caso dentro de un Constraint layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/firsImg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_up_background_gallery"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```